# TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'type' and 'int'```

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

this code:

```
@client.command()
async def history(ctx,user:discord.User,amount= int):
    async for message in user.history(limit= amount):
       await ctx.channel.send(message.content)
```

gives this errror

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'type' and 'int'
```

how to fix ?

Comment: You probably want `amount: int`…?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `amount=int` to `amount: int`.

It gets interpreted as a default argument instead of a type hint otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You declared the default for `amount` to be the *class* `int`, not an integer *value*. Presumably, you either meant that to be a typing annotation `amount: int` (and you'd need to pass an actual integer argument, which you did not do), or you should have assigned an actual integer value as the default, e.g. `amount=10` or whatever default limit makes sense.

As is, `user.history` ended up receiving `int` for the `limit` argument, not an actual integer value, and things went downhill.